# How can I respond to a CLI prompt in Kaggle?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, command-line-interface, kaggle, gpt-2

I'm using Kaggle to generate poetry samples with GPT-2. My notebook uses datasets from [Gwern's poetry generator](https://www.gwern.net/GPT-2#training-gpt-2-117m-to-generate-poetry) and uses [nshepperd's GPT-2 model](https://github.com/nshepperd/gpt-2).

This all works fine with [my notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/theebus/ai-poetry-generator-1-5b-model) when generating unconditional samples.

```
!python src/generate_unconditional_samples.py --top_k 40 --nsamples 1 --temperature 0.9 --model_name=1.5b-model --length=300
```

[image]

However, I want to generate samples with the "interactive conditional" method:

```
!python src/interactive_conditional_samples.py --top_k 40 --nsamples 10 --temperature 0.9 --model_name=1.5b-model --length=300
```

**The problem is when it requests a "model prompt"** and I have no way of entering a prompt.

[image]

It doesn't work when I enter a prompt in Kaggle's CLI.

[image]

If I were to run this on my desktop using my own computing power it would automatically allow me to enter text in response to the prompt.

[image]

**Is there a way for me to enter a prompt in kaggle?**

I've tried to auto respond using flags, like how you would use -y to auto accept a yes/no prompt in installs, but it hasn't worked so far.

[The notebook is public here if you want to test it out.](https://www.kaggle.com/code/theebus/ai-poetry-generator-1-5b-model)

Comment: I don't know how to run your code.  If I create a cell with `print(input("what?"))`, it presents a box and allows me to type.  You should have the same option.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for the response, not sure how familiar you are with Kaggle but following the link to my notebook - you have to click "copy & edit" > then to run it press **"run all"** - it helps if you have an account to access their GPU.

The last 2 cells are the "unconditional" and "interactive conditional" samples I mentioned in the question. **Comment out whichever one you don't want to test**.
You can also change the `--nsamples x` value to only generate 1 sample to save processing time.

Comment: You could probably use output redirection. Something like `!python do_stuff.py < $(echo "this is my input")`

Comment: Like this? `!python src/interactive_conditional_samples.py --top_k 40 --nsamples 1 --temperature 0.9 --model_name=1.5b-model --length=300 < $(echo "this is my input")`

I get an ambiguous redirect error when i try that.